# how to target a sprite randomly

Tags: python

I am trying to create a retro style 2d shooter game and am currently making a homing missile. I need to randomly select a sprite from a group `(pygame.sprite.Group)` and find out its `x` and `y` coords. I have already made it home in on these coords so I do not need help with that. My code is:

an `Enemy class` (they are all the same just with different sizes and pictures):

```
 class EnemyShipLevel1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users    /Me/PycharmProjects/Game folder/SpaceShip game/Enemy1.png")
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.y = -50
            self.rect.centerx = random.randint(15, SCREEN_WIDTH-15)
            self.change_y = 0
            self.cooldown = 0
            self.targetx = 500
            self.health = 1
            if self.targetx >= self.rect.centerx:
                self.change_x = 2
            else:
                self.change_x = -2

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        if self.rect.centery < 200:
            self.rect.centery += 2
        self.get_target()
        if self.targetx > self.rect.centerx+10:
            self.change_x = 3
        elif self.targetx < self.rect.centerx-10:
            self.change_x = -3
        else:
            self.change_x = 0
        self.cooldown -= 1
        if self.rect.left < screen_rect.left:
            self.change_x = -self.change_x
        if self.rect.right > screen_rect.right:
            self.change_x = -self.change_x

        if self.cooldown < 0 and (self.rect.centerx-50 < self.targetx < self.rect.centerx+50) and player.trans is False:
            self.cooldown = random.randint(15, 25)
            laser = NormalLaser(self.rect.centery, self.rect.centerx, False, 0, 8)
            all_sprite_list.add(laser)
            enemy_laser_list.add(laser)
        player_laser_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, player_laser_list, True)
        for laser in player_laser_hit_list:
            if self.health < 1:
                all_sprite_list.remove(self)
                enemy_list.remove(self)
            else:
                self.health -= 1

    def get_target(self):
        self.targetx = player.rect.centerx
```

`Targeting Laser class` (I know you can't bend lasers):

```
    class TargetingLaser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.floating_point_x = start_x
        self.floating_point_y = start_y
        self.x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        self.y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        self.angle = math.atan2(self.y_diff, self.x_diff)
        self.velocity = 10
        self.change_x = math.cos(self.angle) * self.velocity
        self.change_y = math.sin(self.angle) * self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Minecraft/PycharmProjects/Game folder/SpaceShip game/Laser.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -(math.degrees(self.angle)+90))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = start_x
        self.rect.centery = start_y

def update(self):
    self.floating_point_y += self.change_y
    self.floating_point_x += self.change_x
    self.rect.y = int(self.floating_point_y)
    self.rect.x = int(self.floating_point_x)
    if self.rect.top < screen_rect.top:
        player_laser_list.remove(self)
        enemy_laser_list.remove(self)
        all_sprite_list.remove(self)
    if self.rect.bottom > screen_rect.bottom:
        player_laser_list.remove(self)
        all_sprite_list.remove(self)
        enemy_laser_list.remove(self)
    if self.rect.left < screen_rect.left:
        player_laser_list.remove(self)
        all_sprite_list.remove(self)
        enemy_laser_list.remove(self)
    if self.rect.right > screen_rect.right:
        player_laser_list.remove(self)
        all_sprite_list.remove(self)
        enemy_laser_list.remove(self)
```

Game Loop:

```
all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player_laser_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_laser_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
live_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
health_bar_list = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Play = True
player = Player(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT-30)
all_sprite_list.add(player)
player_list.add(player)


for counter in range(2):
    enemy = EnemyShipLevel1()
    all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
    enemy_list.add(enemy)


live1 = LivesIcon(5, 0, 1)
live_list.add(live1)
live1 = LivesIcon(27, 30, 2)
live_list.add(live1)
live1 = LivesIcon(50, 0, 3)
live_list.add(live1)
live1 = LivesIcon(72, 30, 4)
live_list.add(live1)
live1 = LivesIcon(95, 0, 5)
live_list.add(live1)
all_sprite_list.add(live_list)

health_bar = PlayerHealthBar(0, 690)
all_sprite_list.add(health_bar)
health_bar_list.add(health_bar)

ship = EnemyShipLevel3()
all_sprite_list.add(ship)
enemy_list.add(ship)


while Play is True:
    # Shooting
    if player.shooting is True:
        if player.laser_cooldown < 0:
            player.laser_cooldown = 5
            if player.last_shot == "left":
                player.last_shot = "right"
                laser = NormalLaser(player.rect.centery-2,                 player.rect.centerx + 11, True, 0, 8)
            all_sprite_list.add(laser)
            player_laser_list.add(laser)
        else:
            player.last_shot = "left"
            laser = NormalLaser(player.rect.centery-2, player.rect.centerx - 11, True, 0, 8)
            all_sprite_list.add(laser)
            player_laser_list.add(laser)
    if player.rocket_cooldown < 0:
        player.rocket_cooldown = 15
        for counter in range(10):
            laser = TargetingLaser(player.rect.centerx,player.rect.centery, player.rect.centerx, 0)
            all_sprite_list.add(laser)
            player_laser_list.add(laser)
# Shooting
# Levels
if len(enemy_list) == 0:
    all_sprite_list.remove(enemy_laser_list)
    all_sprite_list.remove(player_laser_list)
    enemy_laser_list.empty()
    player_laser_list.empty()
    player.level += 1
    for counter in range(player.spawn_enemies1):
        enemy = EnemyShipLevel1()
        all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
        enemy_list.add(enemy)
    for counter in range(player.spawn_enemies2):
        enemy2 = EnemyShipLevel2()
        all_sprite_list.add(enemy2)
        enemy_list.add(enemy2)
    for counter in range(player.spawn_enemies3):
        ship = EnemyShipLevel3()
        all_sprite_list.add(ship)
        enemy_list.add(ship)
    if player.level == 2:
        player.spawn_enemies1 = 3
        player.spawn_enemies2 = 1
    if player.level == 3:
        player.spawn_enemies1 = 5
        player.spawn_enemies2 = 2
    if player.level == 4:
        player.spawn_enemies1 = 10
        player.spawn_enemies2 = 5
    if player.level == 5:
        player.spawn_enemies1 = 12
        player.spawn_enemies2 = 8
        player.spawn_enemies3 = 1
# Levels
# End Game
if player.lives == 0:
    Play = False
# End Game
# Keys
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Play = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key == pygame.K_a) or (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
            player.change_x = -5
        elif (event.key == pygame.K_d) or (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
            player.change_x = 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            player.shooting = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        player.rotation = 0
        player.change_x = 0
        player.change_y = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            player.shooting = False
# Keys
all_sprite_list.update()
screen.fill(BLACK)
all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
enemy_laser_list.draw(screen)
player_laser_list.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
quit()
```

Each time you kill all of the spawned enemies then the game spawns in more and adds them to `enemy_list()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to randomly choose a sprite then use a random.randint(0, 30) (or the number of sprites) then do a long series of if statements. Example Code.

```
import random
import pygame

class Enemy:

    def __init__()
    random_sprite = random.randint(0, 1)
    # Then put in two variables which equal to the png (I will use sprite1 and sprite2)

    def sprite_render
        if random_sprite == 0:   
            # Just blit sprite1
        elif random_sprite == 1:
            # Just blit sprite2
```

(The reason why I just commented the actions for the image stuff is because almost everyone does it in a  different way and that is not the main point of this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a `number` attribute to each enemy.

For example, you could start off your enemy function like this:

```
class EnemyShipLevel1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    number = None
    def __init__(self,number):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = number
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users    /Me/PycharmProjects/Game folder/SpaceShip game/Enemy1.png")
```

Now when you spawn in the enemies, you would add the number attribute:

```
for counter in range(2): # change this number to use more than 2 enemies (I use 30 later)
    enemy = EnemyShipLevel1(counter)
    all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
    enemy_list.add(enemy)
```

All you have to do is randomly choose the sprite:

```
choice = random.randrange(0,30) # between 0 and the number of enemies spawned
for i in enemy_list:
    if i.number == choice:
        # make i the target of the laser
        target_x = i.rect.x
        target_y = i.rect.y
```